# Adding table with restricted horizontal line

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am new to LaTeX and having a hard time trying to figure out a way to draw a table like the one in the image below.

- To be precise, how do I get the horizontal line only above the texts "Ruin" and "Success".
- Another issue is how to align the text "Probability of" exactly between "Ruin" and "Success".

[image: MWE Tabular]

I tried:

```
\begin{tabular}{c c  c p{2cm}}
\hline
&&Probability of \\
Capital,$a$ & Ruin & Success & Average duration,$N_a$  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` and `\cmidrule` from `booktabs` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{c c  c c}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Probability of} & Average \\\cmidrule{2-3}
Capital, $a$ & Ruin & Success &  duration, $N_a$  \\
\midrule
9 & 0.1 & 0.9 & 0.9 \\
9 & 0.1 & 0.9 & 0.9 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more details on `\cmidrule` refer to the [documentation](http://www.texdoc.net) of `booktabs` package.

A possible refinement for the last header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\smashedcell}[1]{%
  \strut\smash{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{c c  c c}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Probability of} & \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
Capital, $a$ & Ruin & Success & \smashedcell{Average \\ duration, $N_a$}  \\
\midrule
9 & 0.1 & 0.9 & 0.9 \\
9 & 0.1 & 0.9 & 0.9 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HarishKumar If I need another horizontal line, say under the text "Average". What changes do I do?

Comment: @MadhavPai In the first example, use `\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule(l{1ex}r{1ex}){4-4}` (another `\cmidrule`). In the second exabove, use `\smashedcell{Average \\\hline duration, $N_a$}` (extra `\hline`).

Answer (score 1):

or with help of siunitx and multirow

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{booktabs,multirow,siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{S}}
\toprule
                &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Probability of}  &   
                                \multirow{2}{2cm}{\centering 
                                 Average\newline  duration, $N_a$}  \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
    {Capital, $a$}  &   {Ruin}      &   {Success}           &       \\                    
    \midrule
    9               &   0.1         &   0.9                 &   9   \\
    90              &   0.10        &   0.90                & 900   \\
    900             &   0.053       &   0.947               & 450   \\ 
    \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

where for last column instead of showed multirow construction for head of the last column you can use very interesting egreg refinement given in the first answer.