# Horizontal line only above a multicolumn

Tags: tables, booktabs

I have a table in which I want a horizontal line only over a defined multicolumn. I checked some ideas from stackExchange like: [How to add more space underneath and above a horizontal line in tabu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213447/how-to-add-more-space-underneath-and-above-a-horizontal-line-in-tabu) using cline or the one mentioned here: [Adding a horizontal line to a multicolumn field in a longtable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274244/adding-a-horizontal-line-to-a-multicolumn-field-in-a-longtable) However, in my case the horizontal line is not appearing and I don't know why. I also tried the \cmidrule{} keyword that is mentioned here [Adding table with restricted horizontal line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175542/adding-table-with-restricted-horizontal-line) but here I have the problem that the line is shifted to the top a bit which can be seen in the picture below.[image]

A small test code is attached. Any suggestion to shift the horizonal line correctly would be nice to have. Or if someone has another suggestion to achieve that. Thanks in advance. Kind regards Tobi

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.15}
\begin{table}[b]
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \cmidrule{6-9}
 \multicolumn{5}{c|}{} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{gray!10}Annahme Kugel} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{gray!10}Annahme Platte} 
 \\\hline
 \cellcolor{gray!10}ID & 
 \cellcolor{gray!10}Breite &  
 \cellcolor{gray!10}Länge & 
 \cellcolor{gray!10}Breite&
 \cellcolor{gray!10}Länge &
 \cellcolor{gray!10}Volumen&
 \cellcolor{gray!10}Radius (Äquiv)&
 \cellcolor{gray!10}Volumen&
 \cellcolor{gray!10}Radius (Äquiv)
 \\
 \cellcolor{gray!10}[-] &
 \cellcolor{gray!10}[px] &
 \cellcolor{gray!10}[px] &
 \cellcolor{gray!10}[$\mu$m] &
 \cellcolor{gray!10}[$\mu$m] &
 \cellcolor{gray!10}[m$^{3}$] &
 \cellcolor{gray!10}[m] &
 \cellcolor{gray!10}[m$^{3}$] &
 \cellcolor{gray!10}[m]
 \\\hhline{|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|}
1 & 22.0 & 427.6 & 2.03704E-06 & 3.95926E-05 & 1.29033E-16 & 3.13476E-06 & 3.19321E-15 & 9.13509E-06    \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your snippet, which should be a full compilable code, can't be compiled even if completed,  as no one knows what `\tableSettings` is.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. I removed it and updated the whole code. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a classical problem with `\cline`  in coloured tables.  The rules from `booktabs` do not have this problem, but they add padding above and below rules which is not coloured, whence white strips at the top and bottom of coloured rows.

The simplest solution is to use `\hhline` and `makecell` to add vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifiers prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if `siunitx` is loaded). To obtain this padding, one defines *minimal* vertical distances between a cell and the above and below cells.

So here is a possible code, in which I commented `\tableSettings` since I don't know how it is defined. Playing with the value of `\tabcolsep`, I could use `\footnotesize` in the place of `\tiny`, which is practically unreadable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, hhline}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[b]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.9pt}
  \footnotesize
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|*{9}{Cc|}}
    \hhline{~~~~~|----|}
    \multicolumn{5}{c|}{} &
    \multicolumn{2}{Cc|}{\cellcolor{gray!10}Annahme Kugel} &
    \multicolumn{2}{Cc|}{\cellcolor{gray!10}Annahme Platte}
    \\\hline
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    ID & Breite & Länge & {Breite} & {Länge} & {Volumen} & {Radius} & {Volumen} & {Radius}
    \\[-1.2ex]
    \rowcolor{gray!10}
    {[-]} & {[px]} & {[px]} & {[\si{\um}]} & {[\si{\um}]} & {[\si{\cubic\m}]} & {(Äquiv) [m]} & {[\si{\cubic\m}]} & { (Äquiv) [m]}
    \\\hhline{|=:=:=:=:=:=:=:=:=|}
    1 & 22.0 & 427.6 & 2.03704\,E-06 & 3.95926\,E-05 & 1.29033\,E-16 & 3.13476\,E-06 & 3.19321\,E-15 & 9.13509\,E-06 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bernhard, thanks for the reply. First I changed my code with the preamble (totally forgot it) and removed the \tableSettings. I also want to avoid tiny but if I use footnotesize, the table becomes to large and based on the fact that this one is just in the appendix and does not be really analyzed, I guess tiny is still okay. At least the prints are okay. Great solution. Solved my problem.

Comment: @Tobi: I've posted an updated code with `\footnotesize`,  based on your preamble (11pt, &c.). With a slightly different layout of some column heads, it doesn't overflow into the margin.

Comment: Thanks, but the added code is given in text (just as information). Thank you again Bernhard. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily construct that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. In that environment, you have a key `corners` to specifiy some empty corners and the rules are not drawn in that empty corners (if you use `\Hline` provided by `nicematrix` instead of `\hline`).

Moreover, you will have a perfect output in the PDF viewers (some rules won't seem to disappear under the colored panels at some levels of zoom).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[b]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.9pt}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{9}{c}}[corners=NW,vlines,colortbl-like,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\Hline
&&&&&\rowcolor{gray!10}\Block{1-2}{Annahme Kugel} && \Block{1-2}{Annahme Platte} \\ 
\Hline
\rowcolor{gray!10}%
ID & Breite & Länge & {Breite} & {Länge} & {Volumen} & {Radius} & {Volumen} & {Radius}     \\[-1ex]
\rowcolor{gray!10}%
[-] & [px] & [px] & [\si\um] & [\si\um] & [\si{\cubic\m}] & (Äquiv) [m] & [\si{\cubic\m}] &  (Äquiv) [m] \\
\Hline\Hline
1 & 22.0 & 427.6 & 2.03704\,E-06 & 3.95926\,E-05 & 1.29033\,E-16 & 3.13476\,E-06 & 3.19321\,E-15 & 9.13509\,E-06 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: You should add some vertical space around cells contents ;-) (+1).

Comment: @Zarko: You are right. I have modified my answer.